# MINTclass crashing (asking me to log back in), with this workflow

Tags: untagged

If I follow the following procedure, then MINTclass logs me out. I used this one time before, and it is very useful. However this week it is not working.
It seems to be working on my desktop, but not on my work iPad. I have tried selecting request-desktop-site, but this makes no difference, with this problem.

- Choose a class
- Show seating plan
- Choose a student, anyone
- Select points
- Select advanced reporting
- Select student **(at this point I am asked to login again, and when I do it has lost track of where I am)**
- Select «year»
- Select «tutor group»

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround: There is a cookie bug in mint-class, you can fix the problem by deleting cookies. The only option that I found (in chrome) is to delete **ALL** cookies.